# model hasManyThrough relationship using a pivot model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, eloquent-relationship

I have the following models/tables:

```
branch:
    id - integer

department:
    id - integer

teacher:
    id  - integer
    branch_department_id - integer

branch_department:
    id - integer
    branch_id - integer
    department_id - integer
```

- each `branch` has many `departments` through the pivot table `branch_department`
- each `branch_department` has many `teacher`s

I want to model a `hasManythrough` relationship between `branch` and `teacher`s

so from a specific `branch` i want to get all teachers through every `branch_department` that is related to that `branch`

How can I define this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't define a `BranchDepartment` model.

```
class BranchDepartment extends Pivot
{
}
```

From here you can just define the `hasManyThrough` relationship on your `Branch` model.

```
public function teachers()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        Teacher::class,
        BranchDepartment::class,
        secondKey: 'branch_department_id',
    );
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'teachers.' in 'on clause' (Connection: mysql, SQL: select `teachers`.*, `branch_department`.`branch_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `teachers` inner join `branch_department` on `branch_department`.`id` = `teachers`.`` where `branch_department`.`branch_id` = 5).`

Comment: Updated the answer, it can maybe require some more changes. And fairly weird it can't assume the name of that key.

Comment: Still fails: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'teachers.branch_department_id' in 'on clause' (Connection: mysql, SQL: select `teachers`.*, `branch_department`.`branch_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `teachers` inner join `branch_department` on `branch_department`.`id` = `teachers`.`branch_department_id` where `branch_department`.`branch_id` = 5)`

Comment: Doesn't this column exists in your schema teachers.branch_department_id, it is in your question?

Comment: Yes you are right i had a different column name on my side which cause the confusion, now your solution works fine

Comment: Great i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

add branch_department model and:

```php
class Branch extends Model
{
    public function teachers()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            Teacher::class,
            BranchDepartment::class,
            'branch_id',
            'id',
            'id',
            'teacher_id'
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work since my database structure doesn't have a `teacher_id` column